# Добавление роли администратора discord.py

Tags: python, discord

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def admin(ctx, message):
guild = ctx.guild
perms = discord.Permissions(administrator=True) #права роли
await guild.create_role(name="adminus", permissions=perms, colour=discord.Colour.green())

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="adminus") 
user = message.author 
user.add_role(role) 

await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
```

Нужно добавить роль администратора а потом выдать пользователю который написал команду бота. Прошу вас помочь!

Answer (score 0):

```py
role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="name of role here", permissions=discord.Permissions(8), colour=0xffffff)
await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
```